# jquery loop id for div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bootstrap accordion and I'm tryin to get ID and HREF for every accordion in jquery. here is my code

```
$('.room-loop').each(function(id){
    $('.room-loop-a').attr("href", '#'+(id));
    $('.room-loop-body').attr("id", id)
    console.log(id)
  });
```

but id and href for every class named "room-loop-a" and "room-loop-body" is 3. I tried many methods like importing variable ID and in loop make it id+=1, but in attr dont work none of em. any ideas?

Comment: Note, you *probably* don't need an `id=` and even more likely don't need an auto-generated ID.   There are likely better ways to do whatever you think you need id for; either with a single class or data- attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to use `.find()` depending on your html.

```
$('.room-loop').each(function(id) {
  $(this).find('.room-loop-a').attr("href", '#room' + (id));
  $(this).find('.room-loop-body').attr("id", "room" + id)
  console.log(id)
});
```

Problem is that this `$('.room-loop-a').attr("href", '#'+(id));` will set the same href to all elements with the class `room-loop-a`

Also please note it's not recommended that your id starts with a number, so I've added `room` in front, but you can change that to your liking.

**Demo**

```js
$('.room-loop').each(function(id) {
  $(this).find('.room-loop-a').attr("href", '#room' + (id));
  $(this).find('.room-loop-body').attr("id", "room" + id)
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-loop">
  <a href="" class="room-loop-a">room-loop-a</a>
  <div class="room-loop-body">
    room-loop-body
  </div>
</div>

<div class="room-loop">
  <a href="" class="room-loop-a">room-loop-a</a>
  <div class="room-loop-body">
    room-loop-body
  </div>
</div>
```